Movie about little bad monsters
I remember a scene where a man was on the bed with a blindfold and hands and feet tied, as for sex, and he felt pleasure, because a "woman" was kissing him, but really it was a little monster with the appearance of woman (with the size of a rat) on his breast, and she was puking leeches. The movie had others monsters such as a "man" with big arms and little head.
Further details:

I think the movie is from USA and the 90's.
One of the monsters had a similar appearance to Mimi of the Muppets.


Can you remember any more details? What year did you watch this movie? Was it in English? Was it 'hard' horror or 'comedy' horror? Anything you could add would be helpful to finding your answer, and also help avoid this question being closed (as it will be, very soon..)

Thanks for the extra details; posted a match. (BTW, by 'Mimi' did you mean Beaker?)

Sounds like the notorious Puppet Master from 1989 about evil little dolls.

Neil Gallagher found the secret to Toulon's puppets who come to life and then killed himself. Alex and his psychic friends come to investigate and are stalked by Toulon's puppets who have a variety of strange traits including a drill for a head and the ability to spit up leeches.

The movie became a franchise and produced 9 sequels. You can see the scene you've described (with the tiny leech woman and the blindfolded man) here [Warning: Graphic], and here's the doll with the tiny head and big arms (called Pinhead):


Yes, thank you, that it is
